# Having problems with git after accidentally added everything to a new branch

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code

I just started to work with git and github to work with files between my laptop and my desktop. I tried to creat a new branch called "branch_2" and accidentally added everything with the add all command. Now I am stuck with a new branch_2 in Vscode that can't be deleted and untracked files that can't be removed.

```
git branch
```

git branch returns nothing

```
PS C:\Users\carle\Vscode> git status

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        "m\303\245ltider/"
```

I have tried most of everything it feels like now. I have tried:

```
git clean -fdx
```

```
git fetch --prune
```

```
git rm --cached -f måltider
```

But nothing happends. I don't know what kind of weird limbo I currently have gotten myself stuck in right now. My only other option I can think of is to do a hard reset on my laptop (have tried to reinstall vscode, nothing happend).

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to merge the newly created branch back into `main`? Do you just want to discard the local branch? In the second case, the easiest solution to go back to exactly the remote state of the repo is to delete the folder and `git clone` again (this will obviously delete all unpushed local changes and branches). Also, try to keep your filenames ASCII only, as you can see, git escapes `måltider` which could break on some systems.

Comment: @Taxel I guess, you can just clone the repo in another directory, then copy the new files into the freshly cloned local repo

Comment: have you commited the files to this `branch2`

Comment: I want to remove the new branch_2 that I created. Also I want things like git branch to return the branches that I am working within (which right now returns nothing). I deleted git and resinstalled it, but I can still see branch_2 pop up down left in my Vscode.

Comment: I have not commited anything yet

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.